# How to add validators and constraints on Django admin form with bulk inline data

Tags: python, django, database

I have 3 simple Django models to create a reservation system

```py
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Activity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    start_reservation = models.DateTimeField()
    end_reservation = models.DateTimeField()

    max_capacity = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.start_reservation > self.end_reservation:
            raise ValidationError("Start date must be before end date")


class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'activity']
```

My admin forms look like this

```py
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class ReservationAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Reservation
    extra = 0


@admin.register(Activity)
class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ReservationAdmin]
```

When I save an ActivityAdmin form, how can I ensure, that the number of reservations for a specific activity does not go over the max_capacity?

I tried using the clean method on the reservation like this:

```py
class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'activity']

    def clean(self):
        print(self.activity.reservation_set.count())

        if self.activity.reservation_set.count() >= self.activity.max_capacity:
            raise ValidationError("Max capacity reached")
```

But in the console, it prints the amount of reservations before any of the form data is saved to the DB.

For example when I create a brand new activity (max_capactiy = 2) and I add 3 inline reservations, the console says:

```
0
0
0
```

even though I would expect it to say

```
0
1
2
```

or

```
1
2
3
```

And so I am left with an activity of max capacity 2 and with 3 reservations